# How to smooth curves in Graph Editor by Script

Tags: python, scripting

I have an armature with bones. Each bone has an animation data which iI'm trying to smooth.

`fcurves = bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves
 for curve in fcurves:
     bpy.ops.graph.smooth()`

But I don't know in what context and how to get right access to the bones animation to smooth it by script.

Using Blender 2.8. I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to take care of two things: first selecting the relevant bones you want to smooth and second to switch to the graph editor context. For some reason, selecting and deselecting the respective curves did not effect the operator. I rather locked the respective curves I did not want to smooth.

```
import bpy

# types = {'VIEW_3D', 'TIMELINE', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'USER_PREFERENCES', 'INFO', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'CONSOLE'}

def smooth_curves(o):
    current_area = bpy.context.area.type
    layer = bpy.context.view_layer

    # select all (relevant) bones
    for b in o.data.bones:
        b.select = False
    o.data.bones[0].select = True
    layer.update()

    # change to graph editor
    bpy.context.area.type = "GRAPH_EDITOR"

    # lock or unlock the respective fcurves
    for fc in o.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        print(fc.data_path)
        if "location" in fc.data_path:
            fc.lock = False
        else:
            fc.lock = True

    layer.update()
    # smooth curves of all selected bones
    bpy.ops.graph.smooth()

    # switch back to original area
    bpy.context.area.type = current_area

    # deselect all (relevant) bones
    for b in o.data.bones:
        b.select = False
    layer.update()

# currently selected 
o = bpy.context.object
smooth_curves(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import bpy

# types = {'VIEW_3D', 'TIMELINE', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'USER_PREFERENCES', 'INFO', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'CONSOLE'}

def smooth_curves(o):
    current_area = bpy.context.area.type
    layer = bpy.context.view_layer

    # select all (relevant) bones
    for b in o.data.bones:
        b.select = False
    o.data.bones[0].select = True
    layer.update()

    # change to graph editor
    bpy.context.area.type = "GRAPH_EDITOR"

    # lock or unlock the respective fcurves
    for fc in o.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        print(fc.data_path)
        if "location" in fc.data_path:
            fc.lock = False
        else:
            fc.lock = True

    layer.update()
    # smooth curves of all selected bones
    bpy.ops.graph.smooth()

    # switch back to original area
    bpy.context.area.type = current_area

    # deselect all (relevant) bones
    for b in o.data.bones:
        b.select = False
    layer.update()
```
````

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners, short tips and code only posts rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.